# MySQL - Tables With Shared Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables, that look something like this:

Table A

```
time_unix   time_msecs   measurementA
1000        329          3.14159
1000        791          9.32821
1001        227          138.3819
1001        599          -15.3289
```

Table B

```
time_unix   time_msecs   measurementB
1000        565          17.2938
1000        791          12348.132
1001        227          -128.3283
1001        293          225.12938
```

For both tables, I'm using a composite key (made up of time_unix, time_msecs).  These measurement data (measurementA and measurementB) are in two different tables, because there are actually many, many columns (many thousands) - too many to keep in a single table.

I want to perform a query such that the result set is simply my keys and a select few columns combined from these two tables.  Sometimes the times (keys) line up, sometimes they don't.  If they don't, I just would like a null value returned for that column.

Desired Result

```
time_unix   time_msecs   measurementA    measurementB
1000        329          3.14159         (null)
1000        565          (null)          17.2938
1000        791          9.32821         12348.132
1001        227          138.3819        -128.3283
1001        293          (null)          225.12938
1001        599          -15.3289        (null)
```

How to achieve this?  I don't think JOINs are the way to go.  I have otherwise been combining datasets inside Javascript, and it seems terribly cumbersome.  There must be a way to do this on the database side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `union` since there are no `full joins` in MySQL.

```
select TableA.time_unix
      ,TableA.time_msecs
      ,TableA.measurementA
      ,TableB.measurementB
from TableA
left join TableB on TableA.time_msecs = TableB.time_msecs and
                    TableA.time_unix  = TableB.time_unix
union
select TableB.time_unix
      ,TableB.time_msecs
      ,TableA.measurementA
      ,TableB.measurementB 
FROM TableA
right join TableB on TableA.time_msecs = TableB.time_msecs and
                     TableA.time_unix  = TableB.time_unix
order by time_unix
```

| time_unix | time_msecs | measurementA | measurementB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 329 | 3.14159 | null |
| 1000 | 791 | 9.32821 | 12348.1 |
| 1000 | 565 | null | 17.2938 |
| 1001 | 227 | 138.382 | -128.328 |
| 1001 | 599 | -15.3289 | null |
| 1001 | 293 | null | 225.129 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9dc5ae361d6f9deb11e13912c2482869&hide=1)

Comment: Thank you for your help, this works well for me.  Thanks for pulling it into Fiddle, too!

Comment: The join condition for this answer is wrong.  `I'm using a composite key (made up of time_unix, time_msecs).`

Comment: It's an easy fix. I updated the answer and the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You want a full outer join between the two tables:

```sql
SELECT a.time_unix,
       a.time_msecs,
       a.measurementA,
       b.measurementB
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON a.time_unix = b.time_unix AND
       a.time_msecs = b.time_msecs
UNION ALL
SELECT b.time_unix,
       b.time_msecs,
       a.measurementA,
       b.measurementB
FROM TableA a
RIGHT JOIN TableB b
    ON a.time_unix = b.time_unix AND
       a.time_msecs = b.time_msecs
WHERE a.time_unix IS NULL
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```